# Concurrent requests : what best practices?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, concurrency, playframework-2.3

I have a Play! Framework 2.3 project hosted on Heroku with the Postgres Addon.
It handles requests from mobile applications (Post a message).

For different reasons, I have duplicate (twice) rows (messages) in database :

- the app might send the request twice in a short time ( less than 10ms )
- I have multiple dynos that handle requests in parallel
- Event if before writing in DB, I check the message does not exist yet. So I guess the first has still not been wrote when the second comes.

I also tried to write a message footprint in the memcache before handling the request (after form validation). But I still got twice messages sometimes.

The solutions I found are :

- have a unique constraint on some database field (like a message timestamp client-side generated ?)
- regularly check to remove duplicates

As I do not have means to update mobile apps I will script a regular check of duplicates.

Any other idea ?
What are the best practices to handle such concurrent requests ?

Attachement : my pseudo code

```
public static Result submit() {
    User user = MySecured.getCurrentUser(ctx());

    final Form<Message> filledForm = form(Message.class).bindFromRequest();

    .... Some database pre-verification

    if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
        ObjectNode error = Json.newObject();
        error.put("error", filledForm.errorsAsJson());
        return ok(error);
    } else {

        if(Cache.get(KEY_LOCK_FLASH_WRITING+filledForm.data().get("mail"))!=null){
            return internalServerError();
        }

        //Verify this flash hasnt already been handled (requests can come twice from client)
       Message sameMessage = Message.findSame(filledForm.get().mail, filledForm.get().message);
        if(sameMessage!=null){
            Logger.info("[Submit] message already exists" + sameMessage.id);

            ObjectNode jsonResult = Json.newObject();
            .... Processing a result ... no matter this does not happen.
            return ok(jsonResult);
        }

        final Message flash = filledForm.get();

        Cache.set(KEY_LOCK_FLASH_WRITING+flash.mail, "");

        ... some fields initializations like flash.author = new Author();

        ... Then some promises


        return ok();
    }    
}
```

Comment: How *exactly* do you identify duplicates?

Comment: Sounds like you want some kind of insert-if-not-exists? Hard to tell.

Comment: Two rows of the DB contains exactly the same message. The timestamp associated to the message (client side associated) is different (10ms later) but the app might have sent both messages.